# MVVM узнать, какая кнопка нажата

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, button

Я создаю во вью ItemsControl, который содержит в себе структуру UniformGrid. ItemTemplate у него - набор кнопок, которые генерируются на основе ObservableCollection (так как количество этих кнопок динамически изменяется).
Реализация ICommand написана следующим образом:

```
class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public ActionCommand(Action execute, Predicate<object> canExecute=null)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentException();
        if (canExecute != null)
            _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
}
```

То есть в данном примере мы не можем посылать в команду параметр.

Так как у нас ItemsControl, то и SelectedItem у него нет. Но мне нужно знать, какая кнопка вызвала команду, чтобы конкретно у этой кнопки изменить свойства (например - покрасить в другой цвет). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `То есть в данном примере мы не можем посылать в команду параметр.` .... `CanExecute(object parameter)` & `Execute(object parameter)` ??? Используйте `<.... Command={Binding mycommand} CommandParameter={Binding item}>`

Comment: Чтобы у кнопки изменить цвет не надо вообще никакой команды, просто пишите конвертер `<Button BackgrounColor = {Bind myItem, Converter myConverter}`

Comment: @tym32167 Не совсем понимаю, как в данном случае работать с конвертером. Пытался прописывать ColorConverter, но там была ошибка в духе `Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter" к типу "System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter".`
Поэтому это точно не вариант. А VM должна получать информацию о том, какая кнопка из коллекции была нажата.
И да, параметрами мне именно что запретили пользоваться

Comment: `у этой кнопки изменить свойства (например - покрасить в другой цвет)` - если вы делаете по правилам MVVM, то все цвета и другие свойства контрола. это View слой, VM (как вы хотите сделать) не должен за это отвечать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, именно так. В последующем всё равно придётся делать конвертер, но пока что у меня модель хранить в себе не стринговые названия цветов, а `SolidColorBrush`(пока только знакомлюсь с WPF и MVVM, то решил так на первое время). И привязка сделана к `Background`.
Но это не меняет задачи: у меня есть массив кнопок, и нужно у определённой кнопки при нажатии сменить цвет (будь то это просто свойство SolidColorBrush, или стринговое свойство с конвертером во вьюхе - не важно, важно, чтобы значения сохранялись до завершения программы). И как это сделать - я не могу понять

Comment: Итак, ещё раз.
У меня есть список объектов класса в VM, коллекция ObservableCollection. На основании этой коллекции в View создаются кнопки.
Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку команда знала, к какому элементу в коллекции она обращается, и меняла внутри объекта свойство. Как это правильно можно реализовать?
Я смог сделать только через отдельное свойство VM, которое бы меняла контент кнопки, но таким образом сама коллекция не меняется, а мне необходимо работать с этой коллекцией дальше.